# How to create a global tasks in VS Code? (user task)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make "global" tasks, or do I always need to copy the same `tasks.json` into every project directory? VSCode seems to require that the task be in a `.vscode` directory within the current project folder.

Answer (score 41):

**User level tasks** is an available feature since VSCode January 2020 (version 1.42).

From the [Release Notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_42#_user-level-tasks):

> Tasks declared in `tasks.json` are now supported at the User Settings level. If you have a build script that you use across many projects, or if you don't want your tasks in a project folder, you can add your tasks in the user `tasks.json` file. Run the Tasks: Open User Tasks command to create user level tasks and these tasks will be available across all folders and workspaces. Only the `shell` and `process` task types are supported here.

In the **Command Palette** (CTRL + SHIFT + P) type:

```
> Tasks: Open User Tasks
```

Comment: [Global launch configuration](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/docs/editor/debugging.md#global-launch-configuration) is supported Remote, but tasks.json can not.

Anyway, Remote Setting + Local Task can work perfectly!

Answer (score 26):

I'm on the VSCode team. As of VSCode 1.8, global configuration is not supported, but the feature is on our radar: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1435

Please let us know on GitHub if you have any suggestions on how this should behave.

Comment: Some settings like to run a build a java file or to run a java file.  I would like for that kind of thing to be global and recognize like snippets that it is a java project or file.

Comment: See @benshabatnoam answer for anything that is VSCode January 2020 (version 1.42) or later. VSCode finally supports per user tasks.json files, which is much closer to global than per project.

Answer (score 6):

I found that Extension: **Global Config**

> Copies global config files (settings.json, tasks.json, etc.) to
>   workspace config folder

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.global-config

Comment: can you provide step by step instructions to set up Global Config for vscode?

Comment: Just put the files you want globally in ~/.vscode and whenever you want the files to be copied to the current workspace, you can do Ctrl+Shift+P and search for Global Config

Answer (score 3):

Feature is now supported in VSCode-Insiders version, just create a tasks.json where settings.json is located. (On windows it's "AppData\Roaming\Code - Insiders\User")
Global tasks will be overwritten if project's tasks.json exists.

Comment: Imagine this is now supported in normal VS Code, right?

Answer (score 1):

#### For VS Code 1.42 and above

Use the user tasks.json file, which you can open with the `Tasks: Open User Tasks` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). Upon using it for the first time / when the file doesn't exist, it will prompt you to select a template to help get you started. The file is located in [the same directory as user settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations). [Profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles) can also have a default tasks.json file.

The relevant release note is [here in the January 2020 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_42#_user-level-tasks):

> Tasks declared in `tasks.json` are now supported at the User Settings level. If you have a build script that you use across many projects, or if you don't want your tasks in a project folder, you can add your tasks in the user `tasks.json` file. [...] these tasks will be available across all folders and workspaces. Only the `shell` and `process` task types are supported here.

I think that last bit about only `shell` and `process` types is outdated / became outdated at some point in later releases. I can currently get suggestions for other task types in the `type` property, and can select those tasks from the task selection quick pick menu.

The relevant historical issue ticket is: [Test user level tasks #89343](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/89343).