# how to run some cmd code on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to have a command to execute some cmd code.like this:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+b",
    "command": "runcmd",
    "args":{text:"echo 'hello word'" }
}
```

I looked [Making Global Tasks in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046494/making-global-tasks-in-vs-code)
but it has not yet been realized.
thanks.

Comment: Like a build task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With keybinds alone, you cannot make changes to anything outside Visual Studio Code. [The preset list of commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) you can use in keybinds does not yet include an entry for running a command in the command line.

For that, you would have to link the keybind to a build task, which could perform actions on the terminal, even if it doesn't actually build the application.

Comment: What is your point with that? You still can't do what you wanted in the question with VS Code.

Comment: It seems only to continue to use sublime. Thank you.