# Visual Studio Code - Build and debug variable named makefile and exe

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I use VSC to compile and debug a CPP generated test executable. The name of the executable and makefile changes depending on which build I'm debugging, and importantly there is only ever a single executable/makefile in my workspace directory.

I'm wondering if there's a way to simply build/debug the  makefile/exe that is found within the directory, as my current solution is to create a new build task/launch configuration (or update my existing configuration) for each build with the updated exe/makefile name, but this is of course not an ideal solution.

```
"tasks":[
   {
      "label": "Build A",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "vcvars32.bat && nmake /nologo /S /F .\\TestA.mak",
      "group": "build",
      "options": {"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
   },
   {
      "label": "Build B",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "vcvars32.bat && nmake /nologo /S /F .\\TestB.mak",
      "group": "build",
      "options": {"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
   },

]
```

```
"configurations":
[
   {
      "name": "Test A",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\TestA.exe"
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      ...
    },
    {
      "name": "Test B",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\TestB.exe"
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      ...
    }
]
```

Changing the name of the makefile/exe is not a solution here, I'm limited by the tools my org uses.

For reference, I open create a new workspace for each build. Our codebase is auto-generated code, so for each build, each required .cpp/.hpp is generated. Having a new workspace for each build means I don't have duplicates of files. I don't know if this is the optimal workflow for me.. but it works. As such, having some easily transferable/global build tasks/run configurations would make my life a little bit easier.

EDIT:
I was able to set up my task.json for this, just need to figure out for launch configurations :)

```
"tasks":[
   {
      "label": "Build",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "vcvars32.bat && for /r ${workspaceFolder} %i in (*.mak) do nmake /nologo /S /F %i",
      "group": "build",
      "options": {"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
   },
]
```

Comment: if there is only a single makefile in your workspace directory how can you have a `TestA.mak` and a `TestB.mak` in the directory, give a clear picture of your directory/file structure like Unix `tree` command

Comment: that means you have separate tasks.json files not 1 file with multiple tasks

Comment: You can have global tasks.json shared between workspaces @rioV8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046494/making-global-tasks-in-vs-code

Comment: don't use [${workspaceRoot}](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_why-isnt-workspaceroot-documented)

Answer (score 0):

Using the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) you can add a pickFile selection:

Global `tasks.json`

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Build A",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "vcvars32.bat && nmake /nologo /S /F ${input:pickMakefile}",
      "group": "build",
      "options": {"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "pickMakefile",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.pickFile",
      "args": {
        "include": "**/*.mak",
        "description": "Select a Makefile",
        "acceptIfOneFile": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The property `"acceptIfOneFile": true` is implemented in v1.45.

You can do the same for your Global Launch configs in `settings.json`

```json
"launch": {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Test Exe",
      "program": "${input:pickExefile}"
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      ...
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "pickExefile",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.pickFile",
      "args": {
        "include": "**/*.exe",
        "description": "Select an Exe file",
        "acceptIfOneFile": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sadly I cannot use extensions.. limitation of my org :D Thank you though

Comment: @bleuj VSC is all extensions, all the default functionality is extensions, you can copy the repo and build the extension yourself if you don't trust the market place version, you can download the VSIX file and unzip it and see it is identical to the repo files.

Comment: @bleuj If an extension in the marketplace has functionality that the VSC team can't improve a lot they most likely will not add it to the base application. Are you not using the C/C++ extension from the marketplace, and maybe Gitlens, and before bracket pair colorizer was build in you did not use it.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a compound task to build using your `for` trick in the OP:

Global `tasks.json`

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Make Build",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "vcvars32.bat && for /r ${workspaceFolder} %i in (*.mak) do nmake /nologo /S /F %i",
      "options": {"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    {
      "label": "Rename EXE Build",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "for /r ${workspaceFolder} %i in (*.exe) do rename %i TestRENAME.exe",
      "options": {"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    {
      "label": "Build",
      "group": "build",
      "dependsOn": ["Make Build", "Rename EXE Build"],
      "dependsOrder": "sequence"
    }
  ]
}
```

In your Global Launch config use the exe `TestRENAME.exe`