# How can I prevent user tasks from executing on remote connection in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60268391/13642249), a user can define a global task within their user `task.json`. However, on remote connection my task executes. Is there a way to prevent this?