# How to compile a c ++ project on Windows in Visual Studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

There are many options known to work for building a c ++ project for Windows like 
Mingw-w64 and Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

There are also other options that can work but have not been thoroughly tested like a native compiler tool chain.

I am trying to compile a c ++ project in an IDE such as visual studio code.

Is there a tool that can compile a c ++ project in visual studio code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up Visual Studio Code to compile C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-visual-studio-code-to-compile-c-code)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the following question that provide an example of configuration and makefile for compiling C++ project with g++: [Visual Studio Code: Take Input From User](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36964949)