# Why cant I take user input in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, user-input

How can I take a user-input in VS code?
Here's my **launch.json** file:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.interpreterPath}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
]}
```

What else i need to do?

Comment: What code are you trying to use to take user input? Did you try `foo = input()`? Try typing something after debugging starts and press enter

Comment: This already has answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64303122/14132185)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code: Take Input From User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964949/visual-studio-code-take-input-from-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set this.

```
{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
}
```

This question is almost certainly a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964949/visual-studio-code-take-input-from-user#49846389)