# Visual Studio Code is not taking input from keyboard when I use C++ or Java

Tags: visual-studio-code, user-input

While taking input from the user using C++/Java, program is running successful and Visual Studio Code does asks user to input, but when I try to enter anything like a number or a character, it takes no input.

[image]

Comment: is there something wrong with vs code setup as i m able to run C and it takes input from the user normally but with java/c++ it asks for input but take nothing

Comment: Why do you write a comment to your own question? If you want to add anything to the question after you posted it, just edit it.

Comment: Try to do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49846389/14755898

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your program is running in Output tab, therefore it is not possible to take input. Just enable Run in terminal in Visual Studio Code Settings.

Settings (ctrl+,) -> Search settings, look for `code runner: run in terminal` (check)

Note: It is supposed that you have `Code Runner` extension installed.

Comment: Hi @Abhishek Sharma if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to extensions (Ctrl+shift+X) and install code Runner.[image]
2. Go to Settings. (File ---> Preferences --->Settings)[image]
3. Search Code Runner, then check[image]

> code runner: run in terminal