# Programs with scanf don't execute in visual studio code

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, mingw

I'm new to C programming and whenever I try to run a code with the scanf it doesn't execute.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
int a,b,s;
printf("Enter the first no: \n");
scanf("%d",&a);
printf("Enter the second number: \n");
scanf("%d",&b);
s=a+b;
printf("%d",s);
}
```

I get this output:

```
[Running] cd "c:\msys64\mingw32\bin\" && gcc Prog1.c -o Prog1 && "c:\msys64\mingw32\bin\"Prog1
```

and this upon termination:

```
[Done] exited with code=1 in 6.586 seconds
```

The exact same code works without scanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a=3,b=5,s;
printf("Enter first no: \n");
printf("Enter the second no: \n");
s=a+b;
printf("%d",s);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter first no: 
Enter the second no: 
8
```

This is what happens on executing in cmd prompt:

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o08a9.jpg
```

Comment: Isn't it simply waiting for you to type something?

Comment: What does "doesn't execute" actually mean?  What behavior of VSC or of the program do you observe?

Comment: Also, what if you run the program from the command line instead of inside VSC?

Comment: You `cd "c:\msys64\mingw32\bin\"` then `gcc Prog1.c -o Prog1`. Is `Prog1.c` in `c:\msys64\mingw32\bin` ?

Comment: Might be related to this previous question: [Visual Studio Code: Take Input From User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964949).

Comment: What input do you type? How do you run and terminate that program?

Comment: @Thomas nope. It doesn't even print the first statement.

Comment: @Gerhardh It doesn't let my type any input. I run and terminate the programme using the buttons on the top right.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes

Comment: @Garrisson Please go read [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964949).  Do those help?

Comment: @SteveSummit I've checked run in terminal and it says the command gcc was not found but does exist in the current location. If you trust this command, type .\gcc in the command. I tried the .\gcc line in the command line but it still gave no output

Comment: @Garrisson I suspect you have a VS Code problem, not a C problem.  I don't know anything about VS Code, but that question I pointed you to seems to be quite common.  There's nothing wrong with your C code, that's for sure.  You might want to post a question tagged 'vscode', to get help from people who know that IDE and its quirks.