# I can't write anything in C++ output console in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

[image]
I can't type anything in output I want to do normal code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int a , b;
    //reserving for variable
    int sum;
    cout << "Enter a number \n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "enter another number \n";
    cin >> b;
    sum = a + b;
    cout << "Sum is " << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

this is my code. Every time I try entering a number nothing happens.

Comment: From the screenshot, you entered `/n` not a number.

Comment: How is the program being invoked? Ex. are you using an extension? tasks.json? Maybe the way it's being run doesn't realize that it should be waiting for user input and thinks it will get all its input from stdin "immediately".

Comment: The code itself is ok, your problem is your setting. But how should we know what is wrong. Tell us more about your environment. Maybe you need to install "code runner" extension.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964949/visual-studio-code-take-input-from-user

Comment: What is Vi**rt**ual Studio Code? :)