# Internal terminal not working on macos vscode

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-debugger

Im new into programming and at the moment im learning c.
On my macbook I have a problem when trying to run my code, i can´t use the internal console in vscode. If I use the external terminal from macos everyting works fine.

[image: Debug-console]

[image: Terminal]

I tried using C/C++ code runner but that didnt help. Somebody had the same problem and is able to help me?

Comment: specifically, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77357008/11107541.