How to interactively run c++ code in vs code terminal in macOS
I am trying to run this simple C++ code in VS Code in macOS`, using clang++:
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Whats your name?" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hi " << name << endl; 
}

the first cout result is printed in the Debug Console tab in VS Code, and it does not let me enter the input for cin, and in Terminal tab, it just writes this:Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. I know that Debug Console can only show output and it's not for inputs, but I want to run the code in the integrated terminal of the VS Code, instead of running the executable output file manually everytime.
I modified the launch.json file to this:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch C++ Program",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/testcpp",  // Ensure this points to your compiled executable
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"  // This should match your build task label
        }
    ]
}


And the tasks.json:
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
      {
          "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
          "type": "shell",
          "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
          "args": [
              "-std=c++11",  // Specify the C++ standard
              "-fcolor-diagnostics",  // Optional: Makes diagnostic messages more readable
              "-fansi-escape-codes",  // Optional: Enables ANSI escape codes for colors
              "-g",  // Generate debug information
              "${file}",  // This is the file open in the editor
              "-o",  // Specify the output file
              "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"  // Output file location
          ],
          "group": {
              "kind": "build",
              "isDefault": true
          },
          "presentation": {
              "echo": true,
              "reveal": "always",
              "focus": false,
              "panel": "shared",
              "showReuseMessage": true,
              "clear": false
          },
          "problemMatcher": [
              "$gcc"
          ]
      }
  ]
}

Thanks to ChatGPT and the similar searches in stackoverflow, but it still doesn't seem to run my code in the VSCode Terminal.
I have already checked the version of my clang, xcode, codeRunner and c/c++ extensions, and I can properly run the code manually, just not able to run it in VS Code terminal by the run button.

If you're using code runner (don't do that) then those json files are irrelevant. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac for the instructions

read https://stackoverflow.com/a/77357008/11107541, which has a section about macOS. cc @AlanBirtles
