Visual Studio Code terminal dont taking input output in debug mode
I have problem with Visual Studio Code. I wrote simple program to input age and output inputted age. When I just run program in run mode in terminal is possible to input age and it is outputted. But in debug mode in terminal is nothing no possible to input age and no outputted age. Why? Can you help me pls? Adding code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int age;

    printf("\nHello world!");
    printf("\nWrite your age:");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("\nYour age is:%d", age);

    return 0;
}

I have installed MinGW and extensions: C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing and Code Runner. Expecting: Fix the debug problem.

Could you provide the launch.json configuration you are using for debugging?

Aside: I think you should reposition every newline \n output from the beginning of the line to the end, which is typical practice. But where you have a prompt where you want the input on the same line, use fflush(stdout) instead.

how are you running? have you read https://stackoverflow.com/a/77357008/11107541 ?

It looks like when I run debug it dont create launch.json file I created it manually but it looks like is near to empty. now file looks like this: {
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": []
}

Can you post me example of launch.json file and write me what to change in my case to work it?
